# Running Ansible commands as a non-root user isn't working

Tags: ansible

I have a need to run some Ansible commands as a non-root user (e.g. "notme").  The following ad-hoc commands illustrate the problem.  I can connect, become root and execute commands, but if I tell Ansible to become the "notme" user instead of root, it fails.

```
[me@master:~]$ ansible test_host -m shell -a "whoami" -b -K
BECOME password:
test_host | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
root
[me@master:~]$ ansible test_host -m shell -a "whoami" -b -K --become-user=notme
BECOME password:
test_host | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

If I SSH to test_host in an interactive shell and run "dzdo su - notme", I'm able to become the "notme" user just fine.  Running the commands as root is not an option.  I have root access on test_host, but other people who will need to run Ansible plays as the "notme" user on test_host do not have root access, and neither do they have the ability to SSH directly to test_host as notme.  They only have the ability to "dzdo su - notme" once connected to test_host.

What do I need to do in order to have Ansible successfully run commands on remote systems as a non-root user?

Comment: It looks like you're using `dzdo`. Have you configured ansible to use that privilege escalation method?

Comment: Yes, I've set "become_method=dzdo" in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg.   If that wasn't set, then becoming root wouldn't work.

Comment: Have you tried Ansible ping module? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, Ansible ping works just fine as myself or root, but does not work if I use "-b -K --become-user=notme" to run as the "notme" user.  In that case, I get the same result as the second ad-hoc command in the OP.

Comment: Did your run with the `-vvv` flag to see if you could get any other valuable info ?

Comment: I suspect the issue here is that you're trying to combine two privilege escalation messages (`dzdo su ...`).  At least with `sudo`, if you want `become_user` to work, that means the user with which you're connecting must be able to `sudo -u notme`, rather than `sudo su - notme`, which attempts to combine `sudo` and `su` much the way you're combining `dzdo` and `su`. Ansible doesn't know how to combine privilege escalation methods like that.

Comment: @larsks Thanks, that was the problem.  dzdo was only configured to allow doing "dzdo su - notme", and didn't allow doing "dzdo -l notme command".

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was the comment by @larsks, who should get the credit:

Configure ansible to allow "dzdo -l notme command".